# libtool: Version mismatch error: 2.4.6 (expected) vs 2.4.6.42-b88ce (actual), aclocal has no effect

Tags: libtool

On `make` I get this error:

```
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6.42-b88ce, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.6.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6.42-b88ce
libtool: and run autoconf again.
```

I run `aclocal && autoconf && ./configure && make -j4`.

I `make` again and I get the same error! Very unexpected...

I started examining generated `libtool` script.

```
# Which release of libtool.m4 was used?
macro_version=2.4.6
macro_revision=2.4.6
...
PROGRAM=libtool
PACKAGE=libtool
VERSION=2.4.6.42-b88ce
package_revision=2.4.6.42
```

So the issue is these `.42-b88ce` and `.42` suffixes. Where do they come from?

I re-installed libtool with apt-get.

I check its version.

```
dev0@DESKTOP-KK30DO1:~$ apt list --installed | grep libtool

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libtool/stable,now 2.4.6-9 all [installed]
```

Here we see that it is actually `2.4.6-9`, i.e. with `-9` suffix.

Okay... What is going on here? Where do these `.42-b88ce` and `.42` suffixes come from? How to solve the error? Please help to understand the issue.

P.S. System info (`uname -a`):

```
Linux DESKTOP-KK30DO1 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u1 (2019-09-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is inappropriate to add [SOLVED] to the title, or to edit the solution into your question. If you've found a solution that you'd like to share, do so by writing an answer in the space below that is provided for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information. If you don't want to write an answer, you can either delete the question using the link below the tags or leave the question as-is for someone else to answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replying to myself.

These suffixes were in the initial `ltmain.sh` distributed within the library package that I'm trying to build. The reason of these suffixes is likely that the previous developer have built `libtool` from the source code (so `b88ce` and `.42` suffixes can be the hash of the last commit and the patch number).

The solution is to re-generate `ltmain.sh` by executing `libtoolize` [1]. Please note that OSX users should use `glibtoolize` (since OSX has its own command with the similar name `libtool`).

The final build sequence is:

```
libtoolize && aclocal && autoconf && automake && ./configure && make -j4
```

References:

1. https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Error-required-file-ltmain_002esh-not-found.html

Comment: As a side node, you should first remove the original `ltmain.sh`, as it will not be overwritten.